# How to avoid conflict when creating 32 and 64 bits rpms

Tags: rpm

We have to compile binary RPMs for both architectures (i386 and x86_64) for centos. When we want to install both, we have conflicts on common files (like in /usr/include, /bin, ...)

Is there .spec creation rules that help avoiding these conflicts ?

Answer (score 2):

I found a link (others sources seems to agree) :

- [64-bit computing: Co-existing in a 32-bit world](http://www.redhat.com/magazine/009jul05/features/multilib/#rpm)

As I understand it, the answer would be :

- common files must be exactly the same in both packages ;
- binaries must be renamed in, for example, `<binary>-32` and `<binary>-64` ;
- libs should be placed in subdirectories in %{_libdir} (which resolves to /usr/lib on 32 bit and to /usr/lib64 on x86_64)
- if libs are places in %{_libdir} subdirectory this needs to be added to file inside /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ to include these folders for linker